# Shape Mismatch Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am continously getting the error:

"(shapes (10, 1), (10,) mismatch)"

when doing a NumPy operation and I am somewhat confused.

Wouldn't (10,1) and (10,) be identical shapes? And if for whatever reason this is not valid, is there a way to convert (10,1) to (10,)? I cannot seem to find it in the NumPy doucmentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `(10,1)` and `(10,)` is the dimensions of your vector. The first (`(10,1)`) is a two-dimensional array while the latter (`(10,)`) is one-dimensional:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((10,1))
>>> x
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
>>> x.shape = (10,)
>>> x
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

So long as the total number of elements remain the same, you can re-shape your array however you'd like via [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)

Answer (score 2):

In `numpy`,  (10, 1), (10,) are *not* the same at all:

- (10, 1) is a *two dimensional* array, with a single column.
- (10, ) is a *one dimensional* array

If you have an array `a`, and print out len(a.shape), you'll see the difference.